# How deal with usage of dark patterns in relationship with user and business needs

Tags: dark-patterns

The morality of using dark patterns presents an ambivalent dilemma. Are there some guidelines or the framework when the business need doesn't correspond with users?

**Example**

- Business need: Standart newsletter signup
- User need: usage of service/product

Dark patterns- preset when registering, disruptive popup when using a product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the usage of dark patterns a very interesting (and complex) topic.

As it is a very broad area I would start dealing with a concrete example.

The newsletter example could be approached with the European Union GDPR (General Data Protection Regulation). A well known email marketing company offers some information about it:
https://mailchimp.com/help/collect-consent-with-gdpr-forms/

This 2020 study about the use of dark patterns after the GDPR is also very interesting:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.02479.pdf